# Reading 5D MATLAB Matrix from Binary File in C++ and Performing Inference Using ONNX Runtime

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, matrix, onnxruntime

I have a 5D matrix with the shape [1, 1, 512, 320, 2] in MATLAB. I am trying to read this data from a binary file in C++ and perform inference using the ONNX Runtime. However, I'm encountering issues with the reshaping and inference process. Here's an outline of what I'm doing:

In MATLAB, I have a 5D matrix with the shape [1, 1, 512, 320, 2].

```
Size(originalMatrix)
% Output: 1 1 512 320 2

% Reshape the matrix
inputMat = reshape(originalMatrix, [512, 320, 2]);

% Write the reshaped matrix to a binary file
fileID = fopen('inputMatrix.bin', 'wb');
fwrite(fileID, inputMat, 'single');
fclose(fileID);
```

In C++, I read the binary file and perform inference using the ONNX Runtime. However, I'm encountering issues with reshaping and writing the output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <onnxruntime_cxx_api.h>

std::vector<float> readBinaryFile(const std::string& filename) {

    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << filename << std::endl;
        return std::vector<float>();
    }

    std::streamsize size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // Read the binary data into a vector of bytes
    std::vector<char> buffer(size);
    if (!file.read(buffer.data(), size)) {
        std::cerr << "Error reading file: " << filename << std::endl;
        return std::vector<float>();
    }

    file.close();

    const float* dataArray = reinterpret_cast<const float*>(buffer.data());

    // Calculate the number of elements in the array
    size_t numElements = size / sizeof(float);
    std::cout<<"Number of elements  "<< numElements<<std::endl;
    // Copy the data to a vector of floats
    std::vector<float> result(dataArray, dataArray + numElements);

    return result;
}

int main() {


    std::vector<float> input_data; 
    std::string fileName = "'inputMatrix.bin";
    input_data = readBinaryFile(fileName);

    // Load the ONNX model
    Ort::Env env(ORT_LOGGING_LEVEL_WARNING, "ONNX_Runtime_Logs");
    Ort::SessionOptions session_options;
    Ort::Session session(env, "model.onnx", session_options);

    // model takes 1 input and gives 1 output
    // Get model input and output names
    Ort::AllocatorWithDefaultOptions allocator;
    std::vector<char*> input_name;
    std::vector< char*> output_names;
    input_name.push_back( session.GetInputName(0, allocator));
    output_names.push_back( session.GetOutputName(0,allocator));

    

    std::vector<int64_t> input_shape; 

    Ort::MemoryInfo      mem_info = Ort::MemoryInfo::CreateCpu(OrtAllocatorType::OrtArenaAllocator,
                                                          OrtMemType::OrtMemTypeDefault);

    // Model dimensions [1,1,dynamic_size,dynamic_size,2]
   

    // I perform a flip here because when matlab writes the data to the binary file it flattens it column wise
    // so the rows and columns are reversed.
    std::vector<int64_t>  inputDims = {1,1,320,512,2};

    std::vector<Ort::Value> input;
     input.push_back(Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(
                mem_info,
                input_data.data(),
                1*1*320*512*2, inputDims.data(), inputDims.size()));

    // Create a vector to hold output tensor
    std::vector<Ort::Value> output_tensors;
    std::vector<Ort::Value> output;
    // Perform inference
     output_tensors = session.Run(Ort::RunOptions{nullptr}, input_name.data(), input.data(),
                              input_name.size(), output_names.data(),output_names.size()); 

    // Retrieve output data (assuming the output is a single tensor)
    if (!output_tensors.empty()) {
        const float* output_data = output_tensors[0].GetTensorMutableData<float>();
        
        std::ofstream outFile1("op.bin", std::ios::binary);

        if (!outFile1.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening the file." << std::endl;
        return 1;
        }

         outFile1.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(output_data), sizeof(float)1*1*512*320*2);

        // Close the file
        outFile1.close();

    } else {
        std::cout<<"Exited"<<std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My issue lies in properly reshaping the input data and handling the reversed dimensions due to MATLAB's column-wise flattening when writing to the binary file. Additionally, I'm unsure if my approach to reading and writing binary data for inference with ONNX Runtime is correct as the output I get differs from the expected output significantly.

Any guidance on the correct way to reshape the data and handle the reversed dimensions when reading and writing binary data and also correctly using the ONNX Runtime for inference with this data structure would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your array sizes don’t match: [1, 1, 512, 320, 2] in MATLAB vs [1, 1, 320, 512, 2] in C++. But MATLAB is column-major and ONNX is row-major, so you need to reverse the order in one of them. ONNX you’d read a tensor of size [2, 320, 512, 1, 1] and then reorder the dimensions. Or you can reorder in MATLAB before saving to file.

Comment: Note the `reshape` in MATLAB doesn’t do anything, the flattened array you write later will be identical without this step.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I followed what you suggested and my output matches with the expected output.